# Nasty Flaw in my Pyramid Application

Tags: python, database, pyramid

I have had just discovered a really big problem with my Pyramid application. The mongo scaffold implied that event handlers should be used for handling database connections as well. The idea is, when new request comes in, connect to the database, when page is rendered disconnect.
So this is what I did, in my `__init.py__`

```
def connectDatabase(event):
    mongo = MongoDB()
    con = mongo.connectDatabase()
    db = con[Cfg_MongoDB_Database]
    event.request.con = con
    event.request.db = db
    redis = Redis()
    con = redis.connectDatabase()
    event.request.redis = con
    log.debug('newrequest')

def closeConnection(event):
    mongo = MongoDB()
    mongo.closeConnection(event.request.con) 
    log.debug('newresponse')   

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=Dashboard)
    authentication = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(Cfg_Auth_Key, hashalg='sha512',\
        include_ip=False, timeout=3600*24*7, max_age=3600*24*7, reissue_time=3600)
    authorization = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config.set_authentication_policy(authentication)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authorization)
    config.add_static_view('includes', 'includes', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_renderer(".html", "pyramid.mako_templating.renderer_factory")  
    config.add_route('dash', '/')
    config.add_subscriber(connectDatabase, NewRequest)
    config.add_subscriber(closeConnection, NewResponse)
    log.debug('main')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

However I've put some logger into method that is connecting to the database, and discovered the method is being called 10+ times, and if I disable caching in `add_static_view` over 100+ times. This implies that for each css, image, js, the new connection is made. Which is huge overhead!!! The site takes 300ms to connect to database 100 times!

```
/Users/jan/Documents/Test2/test2/data.py changed; reloading...
-------------------- Restarting --------------------
2013-02-01 18:32:48,351 DEBUG [test2.tools][MainThread] main
Starting server in PID 12374.
serving on http://127.0.0.1:6543
2013-02-01 18:34:14,451 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-2] newrequest
2013-02-01 18:34:14,582 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-2] newresponse
2013-02-01 18:34:14,952 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-3] newrequest
2013-02-01 18:34:14,953 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-3] newresponse
2013-02-01 18:34:17,459 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-4] newrequest
2013-02-01 18:34:17,474 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-4] newresponse
2013-02-01 18:34:17,482 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-5] newrequest
2013-02-01 18:34:17,497 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-5] newresponse
2013-02-01 18:34:19,158 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-2] newrequest
2013-02-01 18:34:19,159 DEBUG [test2.tools][Dummy-2] newresponse
```

So the solution so far is to move the connection to Model instead. But how would I know than when can I close connection? Anyone have any better, more elegant solution for my problem?

Comment: just leave it open. it will work fine.

Comment: in production pyramid shouldn't be serving your static media, i realize this doesn't solve your complete problem though..., pymongo has built in connection pooling http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient

Comment: yes, I will be using apache + mod_wsgi in production. Either way, I feel like making new connection is a bit of overhead. What do you guys think about making connection in wsgi middleware and passing it with environ? Bad idea?

Comment: Also, how do I return connection back into the pool when Im done with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pymongo has built in connection pooling http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient

Using connection pooling shouldn't create a new connection on every request

Also, I don't think your pyramid app should be serving static media in production for exactly this reason, apache,nginx are optimized to serve files, and your requests won't have to go through your app

Comment: Ive done testing on 200 request with 50 concurrency using apachebenchmark. Auto_Start_Request=False config with with start_request() yielded best results.

Comment: However now Id like to test using just 1 instance of Connection, thru some sort of wsgi middleware. Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to do this in Pyramid is to use a request property, not a `NewRequest` event. As you've noticed, that event is fired for **every** request, including static ones. Request properties are lazy and only evaluated when you want them, and you can specify they be cached (reified) for the lifetime of the request. I've linked an example below which demonstrates how to add a `request.db`.

https://raw.github.com/Pylons/pyramid_cookbook/master/database/mongodb.rst

Below is some updated code that should work for you.

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    # ...

    db_url = urlparse(settings['mongo_uri'])
    config.registry.db = pymongo.Connection(
        host=db_url.hostname,
        port=db_url.port,
    )

    def add_db(request):
        db = config.registry.db[db_url.path[1:]]
        if db_url.username and db_url.password:
            db.authenticate(db_url.username, db_url.password)
        return db

    config.add_request_method(add_db, 'db', reify=True)
```